# issue with jquery-ui draggable() inside of iframes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, scrollbar

i explain u my problem:
i have a hidden iframe in a page.
on a click i load via ajax some content inside a div located inside the iframe.
the links to the scripts are inside the source of the iframe.
the content i load via ajax should be scrollable and i use a custom scrollbar based on ui slider and draggable (jScrollbar).
i initialize the custom scrollbar as callback of the ajax load function but it work only partially:
the mousewheel feature is perfect but i cannot scrolldown by clicking the mouse.

here is the code:

```
$(function(){
   store_frame ();//write the frame intop the page
   $('.submenu').show();
   $('a#click').click(function(){   
        $("#iframe_sub").contents().find('#text_box .wrap').load('presenza.html', function(){
            $("#iframe_sub").contents().find('#text_box .wrap').fadeIn(fade_time, function(){
                $("#iframe_sub").contents().find('.jScrollbar').jScrollbar({
                        allowMouseWheel: 'true'
                });
            }); 
        });
    }); 
});
```

any idea?

Comment: i also tried with a random draggable div and i had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Issue, the problem is the way events are added inside jQuery code. After the first click, jQuery is supposed to add a mousemove event on the current document but its wrong because it uses document.addEventListener. document here references the outside of the frame, it should be something like :

```
var iframe = TheCurrentFrame; //how to access that??
    iDoc = iframe.contentWindow     // sometimes glamorous naming of variable
        || iframe.contentDocument;  // makes your code working :)
if (iDoc.document) {
    iDoc = iDoc.document;
    iDoc.body.addEventListener('mousemouve', eventHandler);
};
```

I need a proper version of jQuery that know how to correctly attach events when dealing with iframes. I've tried to attach a custom event in my frame that when triggered will call jscrollbar or slider (from the frame then). But seems like I can't trigger anything from outside the frame. Let me know if you find something